# How can a Timespan-Day last only for 8 Hours?

Tags: c#, timespan

I have saved a duration in minutes and want to have an output "1 day 5 hours 30 minutes". Currently i add the minutes to a Timespan and do something like this:

```
TimeSpan ts = new TimeSpan(0,0,1800, 0);
Response.Write(ts.Days + "day(s) " + ts.Hours + " hour(s)" + ts.Minutes + " minutes");
```

But now i am only interested in the working-hours of a day. So when the duration of the TimeSpan is 27 Hours it should not create the output "1 Day 3 Hours". I want to have "3 Days 3 Hours".

Is there maybe an easy way to do that with the Timespan object? Is it possible to change the default behaviour of the TimeSpan? Or do i have to program my own custom Timespan-Class?

Thx
cpt.oneeye

Comment: Here is a hint: `div` and `mod`.

Comment: @theburningmonk: yeah...12 hours would be more realistic, because we are using it to track our own workinghours :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Can you simply use:

```
(int)(ts.TotalHours / 8)
```

instead of `ts.Days`?  Then use

```
(((int)ts.TotalHours) % 8)
```

instead of `ts.Hours`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to implement something like this:

```
TimeSpan workday = new TimeSpan(8, 0, 0);
int workdays = ts.Ticks / workday.Ticks
TimeSpan rest = new TimeSpan(ts.Ticks % workday.Ticks)
Response.Write(workdays  + "workday(s) and" + rest.ToString());
```

Will write something like

```
"3 workday(s) and 3:32"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is my code for those who need it.

DynamicTimeSpan-Class:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace fooLib
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Timespan where you can define the number of hours a day can last (+ days of week).
    /// Optimal for calculating bussinesshours.
    /// </summary>
    public class DynamicTimeSpan
    {
        private int _hoursPerDay = 8;
        private int _daysPerWeek = 5;
        private int _totalMinutes = 0;

        public int HoursPerDay
        {
            get { return _hoursPerDay; }
            set { _hoursPerDay = value; }
        }

        public int DaysPerWeek
        {
            get { return _daysPerWeek; }
            set { _daysPerWeek = value; }
        }

        public int Weeks
        {
            get
            {
                return  (int)(((_totalMinutes / 60) / this.HoursPerDay) / this.DaysPerWeek);
            }
        }

        public int Days
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)((decimal)TotalDays - (decimal)(Weeks * this.DaysPerWeek));
            }
        }

        public int Hours
        {
            get
            {
                return (int)((decimal)TotalHours - (decimal)(Weeks * this.DaysPerWeek * this.HoursPerDay) - (decimal)(Days * this.HoursPerDay));
            }
        }

        public int Minutes
        {
            get
            {
                return _totalMinutes - (Weeks * this.DaysPerWeek * this.HoursPerDay * 60) - (Days * this.HoursPerDay * 60) - (Hours * 60);
            }
        }

        public decimal TotalDays
        {
            get { return (decimal)_totalMinutes / (decimal)60 / (decimal)this.HoursPerDay; }
        }

        public decimal TotalHours
        {
            get { return (decimal)_totalMinutes / (decimal)60; }
        }

        public int TotalMinutes
        {
            get { return _totalMinutes; }
        }

        public static DynamicTimeSpan operator +(DynamicTimeSpan ts1, DynamicTimeSpan ts2)
        {
            return new DynamicTimeSpan(ts1._totalMinutes + ts2._totalMinutes);
        }

        public static DynamicTimeSpan operator -(DynamicTimeSpan ts1, DynamicTimeSpan ts2)
        {
            return new DynamicTimeSpan(ts1._totalMinutes - ts2._totalMinutes);
        }

        public DynamicTimeSpan()
        {

        }

        public DynamicTimeSpan(int totalMinutes)
        {
            _totalMinutes = totalMinutes;
        }

        public DynamicTimeSpan(int weeks, int days, int hours, int minutes)
        {
            _totalMinutes = (weeks * this.DaysPerWeek * this.HoursPerDay * 60) + (days * this.HoursPerDay * 60) + (hours * 60) + minutes;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// "1 week 2 days 4 hours 30 minutes"
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string str = "";

            if (this.Weeks == 1)
            {
                str += this.Weeks + " week ";
            }
            else if (this.Weeks > 1)
            {
                str += this.Weeks + " weeks ";
            }

            if (this.Days == 1)
            {
                str += this.Days + " day ";
            }
            else if (this.Days > 1)
            {
                str += this.Days + " days ";
            }

            if (this.Hours == 1)
            {
                str += this.Hours + " hour ";
            }
            else if (this.Hours > 1)
            {
                str += this.Hours + " hours ";
            }

            // only write minutes when the duration is lower than one day
            if (this.Weeks == 0 && this.Days == 0 && this.Minutes > 0)
            {
                str += this.Minutes + " minutes";
            }

            return str;
        }
    }
}
```